# Adding data to database doesn't work when done from a JSP page, but does work when done from the java class

Tags: java, jsp, javadb

so this is probably a beginner's problem but I'm new to all this and am very confused.

I have a Java Class called User(), which is supposed to add data into the Java DB, and my goal is to get that from user input on a JSP page. When I try calling the addUser() method from the main inside the java class, it works and the data is successfully added into the Java DB table. But the problem appears when I call the exact same method from my JSP page, it doesn't work.

I used the Netbeans Debugger, and what I found was that the method fails on "pstmt.executeUpdate()" in the addUser() method, but why? What's different from the JSP page to the Java Class? Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Just to let you know that calling other methods from the JSP page work perfectly fine, and also that the lines "SQLCon.Connect()" and "pstmt = SQLCon.getConn().prepareStatement(SQL) work perfectly fine", below is my code.

Inside the JSP Page.

```
<%
User u = new User();
out.println(u.addUser());
%>
```

Code in the addUser() Method:

```
 public static boolean addUser() throws SQLException {
    try {
        SQLCon.Connect();

        String SQL = "INSERT INTO USERS"
                + " (id, FirstName, LastName, Email, Username)"
                + " values (?,?,?,?,?)";

        pstmt = SQLCon.getConn().prepareStatement(SQL);

        pstmt.setInt(1, 1); //This is temporary, will make this into pk, not null, and auto increment
        pstmt.setString(2, "first name");
        pstmt.setString(3, "last name");
        pstmt.setString(4, "email");
        pstmt.setString(5, "username");

        pstmt.executeUpdate(); //JUMPS TO THE CATCH HERE

        return true;
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not how JSP should be used.  *my goal is to get that from user input on a JSP page* - what you should be doing is doing a HTML form submit (POST) to a servlet and then the servlet should call this code.  **But** anyway, what exactly is the problem you are facing.  Just saying that it does not work is useless.

Comment: The problem is that the method addUser doesn't work when called from a JSP page, and it fails on the line `pstmt.executeUpdate()`.

Comment: Fails - how does it fail?

Comment: It goes to the catch, thus the data isn't inputted into the table.

Comment: Let's make it simple - what is the output of `exc.printStackTrace();`

Comment: Thank you for helping, the output of `exc.printStackTrace()` had the answer, I'm really sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: You might as well delete this question then.